# Inverter sentido do grafico para horizontal no c3js

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando o framework c3js, como eu altero o sentido do gráfico?

meu código atual.

```
    var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ],
        types: {
            data1: 'bar',
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Para mudar a posição dos eixos x e y use `axis.rotated`.

**Padrão**: *false*

Formato:

```
axis: {
  rotated: true
}
```

[Fonte](https://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-rotated)

**Exemplo**

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#chart',
  padding: {
    left: 60
  },
  data: {
    x: 'x',
    columns: [
      ['x', 'Category1', 'Category2'],
      ['value', 300, 400]
    ],
    type: 'bar'
  },
  axis: {
    rotated: true,
    x: {
      type: 'category'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<div id="chart"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
```